# Rails: Assign values to fields in model

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two fields, first_name and brand_name. User enters first_name during sign in. And if he is an owner, he enters brand_name. brand_name by default equals first_name when the user creates an account. The user can change it later.

For this I wrote this method in the User model,

```
def brand_name
    first_name
end
```

But it sets brand_name to first_name though user enters different brand_name. I tried doing in this way:

```
def brand_name
    if brand_name.nil?
      first_name
    else
      brand_name
    end
end
```

But gives error- SystemStackError:

```
stack level too deep
```

Can anybody help in how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is calling itself, which leads to infinite recursion. Rewrite your method like so:

```
def brand_name
  self[:brand_name].present? ? self[:brand_name] : first_name
end
```

Comment: it is not taking first name if brand_name is blank. It displays brand_name if brand name is present. Else prints nothing.

Comment: That wasn't entirely clear from your question, but I went ahead and updated my answer to handle the case where brand name is set to empty string. You may want to consider validating the brand_name to have length > 0.

Comment: oh, m sorry for that, couldn't explain properly. Thanks for editing question! The solution is working :-) One doubt, y 'self' is necessary? not getting how to use it and when to use.

Comment: `self` was necessary here because I used the `[]` method to access an ActiveRecord attribute dynamically. This would be equivalent to `read_attribute(:brand_name)`, but I prefer this form because it's shorter.